# Error handling principles for Node.js + Express.js applications?

Tags: node.js, express

It seems like error reporting/handling is done differently in Node.js+[Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js) applications compared to other frameworks. Am I correct in understanding that it works as follows?

**A)** *Detect* errors by receiving them as parameters to your callback functions. For example:

```
doSomethingAndRunCallback(function(err) { 
    if(err) { … }
});
```

**B)** *Report* errors in MIDDLEWARE by calling next(err). Example:

```
handleRequest(req, res, next) {
    // An error occurs…
    next(err);
}
```

**C)** *Report* errors in ROUTES by throwing the error. Example:

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
    // An error occurs
    throw err;
});
```

**D)** *Handle* errors by configuring your own error handler via app.error() or use the generic Connect error handler. Example:

```
app.error(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err);
    res.send('Fail Whale, yo.');
});
```

Are these four principles the basis for all error handling/reporting in Node.js+Express.js applications?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Error handling in Node.js is generally of the format A). Most callbacks return an error object as the first argument or `null`.

Express.js uses middleware and the middleware syntax uses B) and E) (mentioned below).

C) is bad practice if you ask me.

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
    // An error occurs
    throw err;
});
```

You can easily rewrite the above as

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res, next) {
    // An error occurs
    next(err);
});
```

Middleware syntax is valid in a `get` request.

As for D)

> (07:26:37 PM) tjholowaychuk: app.error is removed in 3.x

TJ just confirmed that `app.error` is deprecated in favor of E

E)

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // Only handle `next(err)` calls
});
```

Any middleware that has a length of 4 (4 arguments) is considered error middleware. When one calls `next(err)` connect goes and calls error-based middleware.

Comment: Thanks! For anyone who might come across this in the future, it looks like the order of params for "method e" is actually err, req, res, next (instead of req, res, next, err).

Comment: @ClintHarris you are correct, I've changed it. It makes more sense that way

Comment: So this looks great, but a problem I'm seeing is that some errors never make their way to the error handlers you describe, and can only be caught by a process.on('uncaughtException', fn) handler.  The conventional wisdom is to let that happen and rely on Forever or the like to restart the app, but if you do that, how do you return a friendly error page?

Comment: i tried E but my app still crashed. It was from a user.save() operation that had a duplciate key. It was supposed to render error.ejs

Comment: @chovy express doesn't handle all possible asynchronous errors for you

Comment: @Raynos - do you know what's the accepted approach for dealing with these async errors?

Comment: @UpTheCreek you handle them. Generally you use domains and send a 500 to the client

Comment: @chovy Also, just an fyi. The error handler has to be given to the app *after* the thrown/next'd error. If it is before, it will not catch the error.

Comment: next(err) is essentially Express's version of throwing an error, you have to explicitly call it within your own middleware though

Comment: @qodeninja That method is considered a best practice in Express.

Comment: @Paul Nicely said, although there's nothing wrong against using process.on('UncaughtException', fn) as long as you restart the app. 
The problem is that you can not respond to the request because UncaughtException happens on a lower level, outside of the request's scope. In case the errors "never make their way to the error handlers" truly happens, you would've no way of returning anything anyways.

Comment: In E) there it reads `// only handle next(err) calls`. Is that true? In may application this handler is reached by some Exceptions inside middleware (eg `throw`) too.

Comment: what i still couldn't figure out is, what is the format of the error ? I tried next({type: '404'}), doesn't seem working

Answer (score 11):

People at Joyent have published [a really insightful best-practices document](https://www.joyent.com/node-js/production/design/errors) on this. A must-read article for any Node.js developer.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20160205174437/https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors

Comment: Great article, fixed the link to point to Joyent's updated document.

Comment: article not bad: but too much text and not enough examples
it's an article for real professionals

Answer (score 3):

#### Why first-parameter?

Because of the asynchronous nature of Node.js, the *first-parameter-as-err* pattern has become well established as a convention for [userland Node.js error handling](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/errors/what-are-the-error-conventions). This is because asynchronous:

```
try {
    setTimeout(function() {
        throw 'something broke' //Some random error
    }, 5)
}
catch(e) {
   //Will never get caught
}
```

So instead having the first argument of the callback is pretty much the only sensible way to pass errors asynchronously other than just throwing them.

To do so will result in an `unhandled exception` which, just in the way it sounds, implies that nothing was done to get the application out of its confused state.

#### Exceptions, why do they exist

It is worth noting however, that virtually all part of Node.js are event-emitters and the throwing of an exception is a low-level event which can be handled like all events:

```
//This won't immediately crash if connection fails
var socket = require("net").createConnection(5000);
socket.on("error", function(err) {
    console.error("calm down...", err)
});
```

This **can-but-shouldn't** be taken to the extreme to [catch all errors](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html#domain_warning_don_t_ignore_errors) and make an application which will try very hard to never crash. This is a terrible idea in nearly every use-case, because it will leave the developer without any idea of what's going on in the application state and is analogous to wrapping main in try-catch.

#### Domains - grouping events logically

As part of dealing with this problem of exceptions making applications fall over, [domains](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) allow the developer to take, for example the Express.js application, and try and close off connections sensibly in the event of catastrophic failure.

#### ES6

It's probably mentioning that this will change again as ES6 allows the generator pattern to create asynchronous events which are still catchable with try/catch blocks.

Koa (written by TJ Holowaychuck, same original author of Express.js) noticeably does this. It uses the ES6 `yield` statement to create blocks that, while appearing nearly syncronous, are handled in the usual node asynchronous fashion:

```
app.use(function *(next) {
    try {
        yield next;
    } 
    catch (err) {
        this.status = err.status || 500;
        this.body = err.message;
        this.app.emit('error', err, this);
    }
});

app.use(function *(next) {
    throw new Error('some error');
})
```

This example was shamelessly stolen from [here](https://github.com/koajs/koa/wiki/Error-Handling).