# Calling next inside a helper-function?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to setup a simple system for rendering user-input-errors and stopping propogation in express, this is what I've got so far:

```
routingFunction= (req, res, next) {
  //setting up a test in express-validator
  var test = req.assert('access_token', 'required').notEmpty();
  isValid(test, next);
  //non error stuff
}

isValid = (tests, next) => {
    //some more code here, that checks if any errors were found and save tem to the array errors.
    if(errors.length > 0){
        return next(new Error());
    }
};

 //a middleware that catches errors:
 app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
     res.json('error').end();
 });
```

My problem with this is that it doesn't stop the propagation when I'm calling `Next(new Error());`, I could return true/false from isValid and then return next(new Error()), but that would add a lot of bloat to my controllers, is there some better way to do it from within the helper function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In main route file, e.g. `routes/index.js`

```
// Set of func(req, res, next)
let v = require('validator'); // middleware-validators
let user = require('user'); // routes for user 
...
app.get('/smth-route-of-user', v.isTokenSet, v.isEmail, ..., user.get)
```

In `middlewares/validator.js`

```
let v = require('validator-func-list');
...
exports.isTokenSet = function (req, res, next) {
    if (v.isValid(req.body.token))
        next(); // Forwarding to next middleware. In our route next() called v.isEmail
    else
        next(new Error('Token is empty')); // Stop route chain and call error-middleware;
}

exports.isEmail = function (req, res, next) {
...
```

You can join validators to one, e.g. checkUser(), and use only one in route.

In `middlewares/errorHandler.js`

```
module.exports = function (err, req, res, next) {
    let msg = err.message; // Here we see 'Token is empty';

    if (req.xhr)
         res.json(msg);
    else
         res.render('error_page.html', {message: msg, ...});

    // Here we can call next(err) to forwarding error to next errorHandler. In example below it was errorHandler2.
}
```

In `app.js` don't forget to attach error-middleware to application.

```
app.use(require('middlewares/errorHandler'));
app.use(require('middlewares/errorHandler2'));
```

If you need collect errors then validator must push error to `req.errors` (or another field as you want) and call `next()` without error. In render middleware you simple check `req.errors.length` and show normal or error page.

Comment: This is pretty much, my setup, the problem I have is that, after `next(new Error()` and that function is done, it seems like the isValid function returns and runs the code `//non error stuff`, I don't want this, since validation didn't come through.

Answer (score 0):

Code after `isValid(test, next);` always execute. Code below block it, but imho is dirty.

```
routingFunction = (req, res, next) {
  var test = req.assert('access_token', 'required').notEmpty();
  if (!isValid(test, next)) 
      return; // callback called by isValid. It's dust.

  //non error stuff
  ...
  next(); // callback must be called 
}

isValid = (tests, next) => {
    if(errors.length > 0){
        next(new Error());
        return false;
    }
    return true; 
};
```

More better use like this

```
routingFunction = (req, res, next) {
  var test = req.assert('access_token', 'required').notEmpty();
  if (!isValid(test)) 
      return next (new Error('error description'));

  //non error stuff
  ...
  next();
}
```