# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am getting following error in my Node-Express App

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)

To say the least, I have created a helper function which looks something like this

```
const getEmails = (userID, targettedEndpoint, headerAccessToken) => {
    return axios.get(base_url + userID + targettedEndpoint,  { headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${headerAccessToken}`} })
    .catch(error => { throw error})
}
```

and then I am importing this helper function

```
const gmaiLHelper = require("./../helper/gmail_helper")
```

and calling it inside my api route like this

```
router.get("/emailfetch", authCheck, async (req, res) => {
  //listing messages in users mailbox 
  let emailFetch = await gmaiLHelper.getEmails(req.user._doc.profile_id , '/messages', req.user.accessToken)
  .catch(error => { throw error})
  emailFetch = emailFetch.data
  res.send(emailFetch)
})
```

From my end, I think I am handling the error by using catch block.

**Question:** Can someone explain me why I am getting the error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try replacing `throw error` with `console.log(error)`

Comment: in `helper function` or `api`?

Comment: .......... both

Comment: @ic3b3rg This is not a correct way to handle rejections. This will result in another rejection because `emailFetch` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`.catch(error => { throw error})` is a no-op. It results in unhandled rejection in route handler.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51538169/3731501), Express doesn't support promises, all rejections should be handled manually:

```
router.get("/emailfetch", authCheck, async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
  //listing messages in users mailbox 
    let emailFetch = await gmaiLHelper.getEmails(req.user._doc.profile_id , '/messages', req.user.accessToken)
    emailFetch = emailFetch.data
    res.send(emailFetch)
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
})
```

Comment: or you could replace the router with `express-promise-router` as this  package do the  job for you and no longer need to embed the code in try catch block. `const router = require('express-promise-router')();`

Comment: Estus, So Instead of using async and await, if we use normal promises. Can we still expect the error? (without try catch) or should I re-read your answer? (perhaps more carefully this time)

Comment: @VarunBindal Yes, you can expect an error. async/await is just syntactic sugar for raw promises. Any `async` function can be rewritten in plain ES6.

Comment: @estus Why do we need to use next() above? considering there isn't any other route if it throws an error here. Also, removing `next` gives **`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block** (even when I am using `try...catch`

Comment: `next(err)` is there because errors usually need to be handled somehow. If you still have UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning then your code differs from what was posted. You could forget to chain some promise or else. There cannot be unhandled promise if you handle it properly.

Answer (score 15):

I suggest removing the below code from getMails

```
 .catch(error => { throw error})
```

In your main function you should put await and related code in Try block and also add one catch block where you failure code.

---

you function gmaiLHelper.getEmails should return a promise which has reject and resolve in it.

Now while calling and using await put that in try catch block(remove the .catch) as below.

```
router.get("/emailfetch", authCheck, async (req, res) => {
  //listing messages in users mailbox 
try{
  let emailFetch = await gmaiLHelper.getEmails(req.user._doc.profile_id , '/messages', req.user.accessToken)
}
catch (error) { 
 // your catch block code goes here
})
```

Comment: Thanks Sumer, can you please add what you mean by altering my code and include that in example

Comment: Added the details.

Answer (score 6):

You are catching the error but then you are re throwing it. You should try and handle it more gracefully, otherwise your user is going to see 500, internal server, errors.

You may want to send back a response telling the user what went wrong as well as logging the error on your server.

I am not sure exactly what errors the request might return, you may want to return something like.

```
router.get("/emailfetch", authCheck, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let emailFetch = await gmaiLHelper.getEmails(req.user._doc.profile_id , '/messages', req.user.accessToken)
      emailFetch = emailFetch.data
      res.send(emailFetch)
   } catch(error) {
      res.status(error.response.status)
      return res.send(error.message);
    })

})
```

This code will need to be adapted to match the errors that you get from the axios call.

I have also converted the code to use the try and catch syntax since you are already using async.

Comment: Thanks tmcinol, can you please add what you mean by altering my code and include that in example

Answer (score 2):

use express-async-errors on your app

like this

app.ts

```
import 'express-async-errors'
```

Later,configure your application to read the instance of error.

class Custom Error

```
class Error{
  
  public readonly message: string;
  public readonly statusCode: number;
  public readonly data?: any

  constructor(message: string, statusCode = 400, data?: any){
    this.message = message;
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    this.data = data;
  }
}

export default Error
```

Middleware to use on your app -> app.use(youMiddleware())

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'
import AppError from '../errors/AppError'

function globalErrors(err: Error, request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {

  if (err instanceof AppError) {
    response.status(err.statusCode).json({
      status: 'error',
      message: err.message,
      data: err?.data
    });
  }

  console.error(err);

  return response.status(500).json({
    status: 'error',
    message: 'Internal server error'
  });

}

export { globalErrors };
```

Answer (score -5):

I resolve the problem. It's very simple . if do you checking care the problem may be because the auxiliar variable has whitespace. Why ? I don't know but yus must use the trim() method and will resolve the problem

Comment: Please explain what `auxiliar variable` means. It is not clear.

Comment: not clear what this means but think he's proposing a solution that no longer makes this error occur haha