# Is it possible to throw an error from a catch block in a Promise in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, next.js, es6-promise

For context, I'm working with NextJs.

Basically from one of my api pages /api/sendData.ts, I am doing a method call process() which belongs to a separate class platform.ts.

Structure of API code (in sendData.ts):

```
try {
  platform.process(someParam);
} catch (err) {
  console.log('caught error');
  // do further handling here
}
```

Implementation of process() in platform.ts:

```
SomeLibrary.request( {content} )
.then( (response) => console.log(response) )
.catch( (err) => { console.log('throwing'); throw err; } );
```

Currently, this does not throw the error back (or at least I'm not able to catch from the caller), but instead prints out "throwing", followed by "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: StatusCodeError: 401 .....".  I have also tried this:

```
.catch( function(err) { throw err; } );
```

From what I've read, seems like throwing an error in the catch block is actually "returning another promise", so the promise chain isn't really resolved(?) or complete.

How can I throw the err in the catch block so that this error can be propagated back to sendData.ts for handling? Is it even possible to bubble the error back up so I can handle the error from my server-side (./api in nextjs)

P.S. This thread highlights the exact same error I'm facing and none of the responses were able to resolve my issue: [UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53940043/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-this-error-originated-either-by-throwing-insid?rq=1)

Comment: instead of `throw err;` try `return Promise.reject(err);`

Comment: also, you need to `await platform.process()` or your outer try catch does nothing. also for this to work, you would need to return the promise from `platform.process()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is you are not returning the promise from `platform.process()`, nor are you awaiting the response from that async function. thus your catch block code will never run because the code that throws from `platform.process()` is async.

here is the way i would handle that:

```
try {
  await platform.process(someParam);
} catch (err) {
  console.log('caught error');
  // do further handling here
}
```

platform.process (below is an example since we can't see the way platform.process is coded):

```
function process(someParam) {
  return SomeLibrary.request( {content} )
  .then( (response) => console.log(response) )
  .catch( (err) => { 
    console.log('throwing'); 
    return Promise.reject(err);
  } );
}
```

OR (an alternative way to write `platform.process`):

```
async function process(someParam) {
  try{
    const response = await SomeLibrary.request( {content} );
    console.log(response);
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: wow, you are right. it's precisely because process() isn't the one returning the promise. I have made use of the Promise.reject(err) method and it worked! Much thanks, I have been stuck with this for the entire day!

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the try catch block or throw the error in the catch block.
Possibly missing await for promise of process function

```js
try {
  await platform.process(someParam);
} catch (err) {
  console.log('caught error');
  // throw error regardless
  throw err;
}
```

Comment: i'm not sure how that will work; currently the 'caught error' message isn't even printed, which implies that the error wasn't even thrown successfully from the catch block in the promise in the first place, right?

Comment: SomeLibrary.request( {content} ) is that try catch block above in this function?

Comment: probably it's the missing await in the try block?

Comment: yes, the request() method is called inside process(), which is in the try catch block.

Comment: i tried adding the 'await' keyword before platform.process(), still the same; the console log isn't printed so the error still isn't thrown.

Comment: Okay, can you please reproduce your error in a sandbox? https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Or add the full implementation of `platform.process(someParam)`

Comment: hi Julian, another user has managed to provide the solution. thanks for responding so promptly, i still appreciate the help nonetheless