# When to use return next(error) vs return res.sendStatus in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm creating a backend REST Api server in Node.js using express and I'm trying to understand what the "correct" way of telling the client that an error has occurred and to not continue on with the middlewares

In my current code...

If I have the route 
`router.post('/test', [first, second]);`

If there is no error, I do `return next()` in `first` to run the second function and then `return res.sendStatus(200)` in `second`

This is correct, right?

But now let's say an error occurs in `first` does it make sense to do `return res.sendStatus(500)` or `return next(new Error('Error has occurred'))`

Or should I do

```
res.sendStatus(500)
return next(new Error('error occurred'))
```

Or is there a way to just send the statusCode inside of return `next(error)`

My understanding is that using a `return` stops the continuation of the middlewares anyway, so I'm not sure how to do this?

Should I only use `next()` to continue and never use `next(error)` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express next function, what is it really for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133071/express-next-function-what-is-it-really-for)

Comment: @DanO Not quite. I do understand that next is for continuing onto the chain of middlewares. I guess I just don't understand the best way to stop and send a statuscode to the client