# Express Passport (node.js) error handling

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I've looked at how error handling should work in node via [this question *Error handling principles for Node.js + Express.js applications?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151487/error-handling-principles-for-nodejs-express-apps), but I'm not sure what passport's doing when it fails authentication. I have the following LocalStrategy:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password' },
  function(email, password, next) {
 
    User.find({email: UemOrUnm}, function(err, user){
      if (err) { console.log('Error > some err'); return next(err); }
      if (!user) { console.log('Error > no user'); return next('Incorrect login or password'); } 

      if (password != user.password) {
        return next(Incorrect login or password);
      }
      return next(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

After I see 'Error > some err' console printout, nothing else happens. I would think it should continue on the the next path with an error parameter, but it doesn't seem to do that. What's going on?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

The strategy-implementation works in conjunction with `passport.authenticate` to both authenticate a request, and handle success/failure.

Say you're using this route (which is passed an e-mail address and a password):

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: '/loggedin',
  failureRedirect: '/login', // see text
  failureFlash: true // optional, see text as well
});
```

This will call the code in the strategy, where one of three conditions can happen:

1. An internal error occurred trying to fetch the users' information (say the database connection is gone); this error would be passed on: `next(err)`; this will be handled by Express and generate an HTTP 500 response;
2. The provided credentials are invalid (there is no user with the supplied e-mail address, or the password is a mismatch); in that case, you don't generate an error, but you pass a `false` as the user object: `next(null, false)`; this will trigger the `failureRedirect` (if you don't define one, a HTTP 401 Unauthorized response will be generated);
3. Everything checks out, you have a valid user object, so you pass it along: `next(null, user)`; this will trigger the `successRedirect`;

In case of an invalid authentication (but not an internal error), you can pass an extra message along with the callback:

```
next(null, false, { message : 'invalid e-mail address or password' });
```

If you have used `failureFlash` *and* installed [the connect-flash middleware](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash), the supplied message is stored in the session and can be accessed easily to, for example, be used in a template.

**EDIT:** it's also possible to completely handle the result of the authentication process yourself (instead of Passport sending a redirect or 401):

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err); // will generate a 500 error
    }
    // Generate a JSON response reflecting authentication status
    if (! user) {
      return res.send({ success : false, message : 'authentication failed' });
    }
    // ***********************************************************************
    // "Note that when using a custom callback, it becomes the application's
    // responsibility to establish a session (by calling req.login()) and send
    // a response."
    // Source: http://passportjs.org/docs
    // ***********************************************************************
    req.login(user, loginErr => {
      if (loginErr) {
        return next(loginErr);
      }
      return res.send({ success : true, message : 'authentication succeeded' });
    });      
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: I used your custom auth code, but when i call req.isAuthenticated on future requests i get false

Comment: @pka2012 I assume that the initial authentication worked, though? If so, make sure Express' session handling is properly configured.

Comment: @thebiglebowski11 (I think) you still need to call req.logIn(). This answer demonstrates it http://stackoverflow.com/a/26032067/2278963

Comment: upvoted! does this work for google strategy, i want to handle the redirect and logging in the user myself for google auth, if I used this callback, how would I manage redirects

Answer (score 22):

What Christian was saying was you need to add the function

```
req.login(user, function(err){
  if(err){
    return next(err);
  }
  return res.send({success:true});
});
```

So the whole route would be:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err); // will generate a 500 error
    }
    // Generate a JSON response reflecting authentication status
    if (! user) {
      return res.send(401,{ success : false, message : 'authentication failed' });
    }
    req.login(user, function(err){
      if(err){
        return next(err);
      }
      return res.send({ success : true, message : 'authentication succeeded' });        
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

source: [http://passportjs.org/guide/login/](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/login/)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `req.logIn(function (err) { });` and do the success redirect inside the callback function

Comment: Can you please clarify your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Some time has passed and now the most right code will be:

```
  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err); // will generate a 500 error
    }
    // Generate a JSON response reflecting authentication status
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).send({ error: 'Authentication failed' });
    }
    req.login(user, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      return res.status(202).send({ error: 'Authentication succeeded' });    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread very useful!

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/issues/2

You could use this to return error and render it in form.

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/home', failWithError: true }),
  function(err, req, res, next) {
    // handle error
    return res.render('login-form');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got after `console.log(req)` at the failler route.

```
const localStrategy = new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: "email" }, verifyUser);

passport.use(localStrategy);

const authenticateWithCredentials = passport.authenticate("local", {
  failureRedirect: "/api/auth/login-fail",
  failureMessage: true,
});
```

validation method find your user from db and throw error to the cb if there is any

```
const verifyUser = async (email, password, cb) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (!user) return cb(null, false, { message: "email/password incorrect!" });

  const isMatched = await user.comparePassword(password);
  if (!isMatched)
    return cb(null, false, { message: "email/password incorrect!" });

  cb(null, {
    id: user._id,
    email,
    name: user.name,
  });
};
```

now setup your route

```
router.post("/sign-in", authenticateWithCredentials,(req, res) => {
  res.json({user: req.user})
});

router.get("/login-fail", (req, res) => {
  let message = "Invalid login request!";

  // if you are using typescript cast the sessionStore to any 
  const sessions = req.sessionStore.sessions || {};
  for (let key in sessions) {
    const messages = JSON.parse(sessions[key])?.messages;
    if (messages.length) {
      message = messages[0];
      break;
    }
  }

  res.status(401).json({ error: message });
});
```