# Passport.js sending error back to frontend

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I have a problem to send back error message back to fronted while logging in with passport.js.

Here's my route:

```
users.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(201);
  },
);
```

And the strategy:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
  },
  async (username, password, done) => {
    // let's assume we are checking here if there is a user in db

    if(user) {
      if(bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
        return done(null, user);
      }
    } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'No user in db' });
    }
  }
));
```

This gives me `401 Anauthorized` error in the browser. However I'd like to pass message ('No user in db') as well and maybe change status code.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, the first parameter in the callback is the error parameter

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
  },
  async (username, password, done) => {
    // let's assume we are checking here if there is a user in db

    if(user) {
      if(bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
        return done(null, user);
      }
    } else {
        return done({ message: 'No user in db' }, false);
    }
  }
));
```

Comment: Yes, I can see it now on the frontend but unfortunately I'm getting it under `500` status code error

Comment: I tried on one of my custom strategies, and it is still giving me a 401. weird

Comment: That is weird indeed, but anyway how can I change status code?

Comment: First answer has the solution for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711127/express-passport-node-js-error-handling